# How to automatically copy calendar events from one Internet Calendar to another in Outlook 2016

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar

So, I have two Internet calendars in Outlook. One that brings ical feed from BambooHR and the other one from SharePoint Online. I can manually copy calendar Items from one calendar to another by changing the view to a "List". How can I copy Items automatically such that whenever a new Item is added to Calendar 1 it gets automatically copied to calendar 2.

Answer (score 0):

I’m afraid that there is no such a built-in option in Outlook to realize this. But I find one article here: [VBA: Copy New Appointments to Another Calendar](https://www.slipstick.com/developer/copy-new-appointments-to-another-calendar-using-vba/). We may use VBA code to copy events to another calendar.